# build set lazily in clojure

Tags: clojure, set, lazy-evaluation

I've started to learn clojure but I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around certain concepts. For instance, what I want to do here is to take this function and convert it so that it calls get-origlabels lazily.

```
(defn get-all-origlabels []
    (set (flatten (map get-origlabels (range *song-count*)))))
```

My first attempt used recursion but blew up the stack (*song-count* is about 10,000). I couldn't figure out how to do it with tail recursion.

get-origlabels returns a set each time it is called, but values are often repeated between calls. What the get-origlabels function actually does is read a file (a different file for each value from 0 to *song-count*-1) and return the words stored in it in a set.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
-Philip

Answer (score 8):

You can get what you want by using `mapcat`. I believe putting it into an actual Clojure set is going to de-lazify it, as demonstrated by the fact that `(take 10 (set (iterate inc 0)))` tries to realize the whole set before taking 10.

```
(distinct (mapcat get-origlabels (range *song-count*)))
```

This will give you a lazy sequence. You can verify that by doing something like, starting with an infinite sequence:

```
(->> (iterate inc 0)
     (mapcat vector)
     (distinct)
     (take 10))
```

You'll end up with a seq, rather than a set, but since it sounds like you really want laziness here, I think that's for the best.

Comment: +1 for explaining that set "de-lazifies" the sequence. Now we desperately need a verb for that.

Comment: "To realize" the sequence is the standard verb for this; I seem to have lazified out of recalling it :)

Comment: (iterate inc 0) is the same as (range) so you could shorten it a little.

Comment: You can also say the opposite of lazy is "eager." The `set` function is eager.

Answer (score 1):

This may have better stack behavior

```
(defn get-all-origlabels []
    (reduce (fn (s x) (union s (get-origlabels x))) ${} (range *song-count*)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use something like:

```
(into #{} (mapcat get-origlabels (range *song-count*)))
```

In general, "into" is very helpful when constructing Clojure data structures. I have this mental image of a conveyor belt (a sequence) dropping a bunch of random objects into a large bucket (the target collection).